# Internet Sharing on Mac via LAN

Tags: mac, internet, ethernet, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet Sharing is grey out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74161/internet-sharing-is-grey-out)

My Mac is connected to internet using WiFi and its working fine. I want to share the internet connection via LAN but I am unable to select the port (Ethernet) to be used for sharing in the internet sharing menu. Please see the screenshot attached.

[image: Internet Sharing Mac Problem]

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: What type of computer are you using?

Comment: How is your WiFi connection configured? Have you tried removing the Ethernet interface from the list of network devices and readding it?

Comment: I was having this problem when i was using MacBook Pro in my office. I am no longer using it. So cannot do further experiments with it.

@MacLemon: I almost never used Ethernet Interface (i am assuming that by removing/readding the interface you mean plugging/unplugging the ethernet wire).

Comment: No, I actually meant removing the interface from the System Preferences > Network > Interfaces list on the left. Had I meant to unplug/replug the cable I would have said so.