# What is disabling internet sharing on my macbook?

Tags: mac, internet-sharing

I bought my computer from my school, where they had multiple locks and disabled functions. When I bought it they were suppose to delete all these locks, but I guess they didn't – now I am unable to activate my internet sharing like described in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74161/internet-sharing-is-grey-out).

I can mess with the options, but I cannot click on for internet sharing.

Can someone walk me through the process of deleting this from my system so I can turn on my internet sharing?

Comment: Are there any other user accounts?  Are you an admin?  To check, to go [System Preferences -> Users and Groups](http://www.warrenpena.com/skitch/Screenshot_2_10_13_8_34_PM_16C89173.png).  Also, under System Preferences -> Mail, Contacts, and Calendars, are there any accounts on the left that you did not set up?

Comment: Your question mentions both Internet sharing and file sharing.  Which is it?

Comment: sorry I meant to ask about the internet sharing

Comment: right now I am the only administrator

Answer (score 1):

One possibility why you are unable to enable internet sharing is your school may have used  a Profile Manager (http://help.apple.com/profilemanager/mac/2.1/#apd0E2214C6-50F0-48C9-A482-74CEA1D77A9F) to apply settings and preferences to your Mac. The benefit is settings (such as WiFi network access, software licenses, etc) present in your Mac allows you to use your Mac in school without having to remember to the settings. Disadvantage is you may have to ask your school for help in enabling internet sharing. Whether the school agrees will depend on its policy for accessing school resources even though the Mac is yours (as you stated, bought by you).

Comment: So I would have to go to the school I bought it from and get them to enable internet sharing?

Comment: If your Mac (bought at the school) doesn't allow you to enable Internet Sharing, and you're the administrator of your Mac, you should bring it in and ask the school to help (and if indeed the school applied the Profile Manager, then you hopefully also learn the school's reason to why Internet Sharing is disabled).